# How do I access properties of an object when inside another custom object in Xcode / Obj C?

Tags: object, properties, null, setter, getter

As I newbie I sort of understand how to create and access properties for an object with dot notation.. eg I have an object golfCourse with a property courseName so golfCourse.courseName=@"My Course" works OK. My problem is that if I create a "holeObject" containing Par and Distance and create Hole1, Hole2 etc inside my Course Object trying to access them by golfCourse.Hole1.Par is returning null... My various searches have not found me any clarity.. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

```
HoleObject.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HoleObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* par;
@property(nonatomic,weak) NSString* yellowDistance;
@end

HoleObject.m
#import "HoleObject.h"

@implementation HoleObject

@synthesize
par=_par,
yellowDistance=_yellowDistance,


-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder
{
  [encoder encodeObject:self.par forKey:@"Par"];
  [encoder encodeObject:self.yellowDistance forKey:@"YellowDistance"];

}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
  if((self=[super init]))
  {
    self.par=[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Par"];
    self.yellowDistance=[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"YellowDistance"];
   }
  return  self;
}
@end

CourseObject.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "HoleObject.h"

@interface CourseObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* courseName;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* courseAddress;
@property(nonatomic,strong)HoleObject* hole1;
@property(nonatomic,weak)HoleObject* hole2;
etc...
@end

CourseObject.m
#import "CourseObject.h"

@implementation CourseObject

@synthesize
courseName=_courseName,
courseAddress=_courseAddress,
hole1=_hole1,
 etc;

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder
{
  [encoder encodeObject:self.courseName forKey:@"CourseName"];
  [encoder encodeObject:self.courseName forKey:@"CourseAddress"];
  [encoder encodeObject:self.hole1 forKey:@"Hole1"];
  etc;  
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
  if((self = [super init]))
  {
    self.courseName=[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"CourseName"];
    self.courseAddress=[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"CourseAddress"];
    self.hole1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Hole1"];
    self.hole2 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Hole2"];
etc;
  }
  return self;
}   

@end
```

Then in my main View Controller..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


  allCourses=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
  CourseObject*thisCourse;

  thisCourse=[[CourseObject alloc]init];
  thisCourse.courseName=@"Branston";
  thisCourse.courseAddress=@"The World";

  thisCourse.hole1.par=@"4";

  thisCourse.hole1.yellowDistance=@"336";
```

but if I then try and NSLog thisCourse.hole1.par Im getting null?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Could you provide some example code related to your problem?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but might make things a bit easier on yourself in the future... instead of creating 18 (as you said in your 'Answer') hole properties, you could create an property that's an NSArray (or NSMutableArray), call it something like `holes`, and create the 18 holes within that. You'd still need to initialize the `holes` property, as well as the 18 holes, but you could turn the 18 initializes into a loop, greatly reducing the amount of code. Also, you'd be able to pass a `NSInteger` (or similar) around and use that index to point to specific hole for that course.

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time trying different things with this as it was pretty clear that the Null was showing the object was not being created properly.. Found that [[CourseObject alloc]init] does not actually do anything for the objects "sub-Objects" and I needed to do course.hole1=[[HoleObject alloc] init] for all 18 holes as well... bit fiddly but seems to work..